# Declare variables within similar class

Tags: java, android

In my Android project, I just made something like this:

```
Person person;

void onSucceed(Doc doc) {
    person.setName(doc.getName);
    person.setAddres(doc.getAddres);
    ...
    person.setAge(doc.getAge);
}
```

These two classes are not the same, but they have a lot of similar variables. Is there any faster method to not repeatedly write `person.set...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a method in the `Person` class to gather the details from the `Doc` object.

```
    public void useDetails(Doc doc) {
        setName(doc.getName());
        setAddres(doc.getAddres());
        setAge(doc.getAge());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can let the class  `Doc`  inherit parts of their attributes from  `Person` .

Example:

```
public class Person
{
  protected int age;
  protected String name;
  protected Address addr;

  //****** SETTER / GETTER ****

}


public class Doc extends Person
{
  private Location medical_center;
  private Family fam;
  private int income;
  //etc


  //**** GETTER /SETTER ****

}
```

By doing so you can create a new  `Doc`  object and still use the getter and setter from the  `Person`  class. But the most important is, that as many other classes as you like to, can extend person.

Update: This solution does only make sense when Doc represents something like a  doctor or anything else that is related to a Person.

Comment: If a Doc is short-hand for something like 'Document', it has no reason to extend the Person class - that's a very poor design decision for no reason other than to save some once-off typing.  If it's shorthand for Doctor, then perhaps there's a case for extending the Person class.

Comment: @RiaanNel Oh yeah that is my mistake. I tought that 'Doc' was a doctor and not a document. In that case my solution is horrible.

Comment: like @RiaanNel said - there is no sense to extend person. 
That might be document.  :(

Comment: @rosinek Okay, that is totaly my fault. Another solution would be to create a method like OldCurmudgeon mentioned in his/ her answer or to overload the constructor of  `Person` so you can create a new Person off of a `Doc` and let the constructor handle the assignments. If you need an example for that i can edit the post to fit the need.